# Testing property set by async method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, async-await, nunit

I try to test a class with NUnit that contains async methods. I don't know how to do it in a correct way.

I have a class with that looks like this:

```cs
public class EditorViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public void SetIdentifier(string identifier)
    {
         CalcContentAsync();
    }

    private async void CalcContentAsync()
    {
         await SetContentAsync();
         DoSomething();
    } 

    private async Task SetContentAsync()
    {
        Content = await Task.Run<object>(() => CalculateContent());
        RaisePropertyChanged("Content");
    }

    public object Content { get; private set; }

    ...
}
```

How can I write a Test in NUnit, that checks, that the Content-Property is set to the right value? I want to do something like that:

```cs
[Test]
public void Content_WhenModifierIsXXX_ReturnsSomeViewModel()
{
    var viewModel = new EditorViewModel();

    viewModel.SetIdentifier("XXX");

    Assert.That(viewModel.Content, Is.InstanceOf<ISomeContentViewModel>());
}
```

But that doesn't work. Because the asynchronous code has not been executed before the assertion.

Comment: Is it just a typo that there is no async on SetIdentifier?

Comment: @Domysee I think so because it can't compile in other way.

Comment: [Avoid async void](http://haacked.com/archive/2014/11/11/async-void-methods/).  Seriously - don't do this. You can't test it, no calling code can ever await completion.

Comment: I'm not so confirm with async and await. My intent was to do the `DoSomething()` method in parallel with the calculation of the content. Is this not the right way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `SetIdentifier` method is `async` too (or you need to make it `async` because you wait operation inside it. Then your method can looks like next one:

```
public async Task SetIdentifier(string identifier)
{
     await SetContentAsync();
     DoSomething();
}
```

And now you can just await it in your unit test:

```
[Test]
public async Task Content_WhenModifierIsXXX_ReturnsSomeViewModel()
{
    var viewModel = new EditorViewModel();

    await viewModel.SetIdentifier("XXX");

    Assert.That(viewModel.Content, Is.InstanceOf<ISomeContentViewModel>());
}
```

You can also use workaround to call your test in a sync manner:

```
[Test]
public async Task Content_WhenModifierIsXXX_ReturnsSomeViewModel()
{
    Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        var viewModel = new EditorViewModel();

        await viewModel.SetIdentifier("XXX");

        Assert.That(viewModel.Content, Is.InstanceOf<ISomeContentViewModel>());
    }).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}
```

Via [MSDN Magazine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn818493.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I changed the code a bit, because i missed a method. Maybe the `async void` is the problem.

Comment: `async void` is part of the problem. async void indicates that you want to run the code async, but not wait for the result. If you are not waiting for the result, your test will continue and run tests before your test setup is complete. async void is mainly used for events because you don't want the event code to block the emitter of the event (such as the message loop). When you are testing, you must use `async Task`, because you must wait for the work to be complete before you test it. Your test method must also be async Task so that NUnit can await and check the results of your test.

Answer (score 0):

When working with `async` you should *always* return a Task. Otherwise it would be "fire and forget", and you have absolutely no way of interacting with the `Task`.

Therefore you should change the signature of SetIdentifier to return a `Task`, like this:

```
public async Task SetIdentifier(string identifier)
{
     await SetContentAsync();
     DoSomething();
}
```

Then you can wait for the operation to complete in the test:

```
[Test]
public async void Content_WhenModifierIsXXX_ReturnsSomeViewModel()
{
    var viewModel = new EditorViewModel();

    await viewModel.SetIdentifier("XXX");

    Assert.That(viewModel.Content, Is.InstanceOf<ISomeContentViewModel>());
}
```

Or, if your test runner does not support `async`:

```
[Test]
public void Content_WhenModifierIsXXX_ReturnsSomeViewModel()
{
    var viewModel = new EditorViewModel();

    viewModel.SetIdentifier("XXX").Wait();

    Assert.That(viewModel.Content, Is.InstanceOf<ISomeContentViewModel>());
}
```